# Как сделать автозагрузку программы в windows(xp,7,8,10)?

Tags: windows, qt

Как сделать автозагрузку программы в  windows(xp,7,8,10)?.

Пробовал следующим образом:

```
if (auto_run)
{
    QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", QSettings::NativeFormat);
    settings.setValue("ALTVPN", QDir::toNativeSeparators(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()));
    settings.sync();
}
else
{
    QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", QSettings::NativeFormat);
        settings.remove("ALTVPN");
        settings.sync();
}
```

В реестре ничего не появляется.

Программа спрашивает права администратора при запуске.

Comment: Например, нет прав...

Comment: Программа спрашивает права администратора при запуске

Comment: Значит, с шансами Registry reflection/redirection. Вроде Qt не умеет с таким работать, так что WinAPI в помощь.

Comment: Запись в HKEY_CURRENT_USER не требует прав.